# clear canvas dicom image viewer

Tags: image-processing, dicom, clearcanvas

Anybody know what is the base component used for viewing a DICOM image in the Clear Canvas image viewer?

Let me add more info.,

1. Please refer to http://www.clearcanvas.ca/dnn/

Its a good DICOM Image Viewer, I think they used a user control.

Comment: Have you walked through the code?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is a control that they built. Look at their Application Framework (as opposed to their DICOM framework). There is a section on their forum dedicated to the App Framework